# Does microsoft web optimization framework supports css @import?

Tags: asp.net, .net, css, asp.net-mvc, web-optimization

In `BundleConfig` i'm defining css file list. If any of this files has @import rules( `@import url('/css/typography.css');` ), will this framework minimize target css file as well?

Thank you